Tumblr posts don't show images when viewed from homepage, only when I enter the post does the picture show?
I hope someone can help me find a solution to this.
I have a problem with my tumblr photo posts showing correctly on my blog.
When you are on homepage and scroll down to the "portfolio-post" section, even though the posts have images, they don't load on homepage (an example)
They DO LOAD once you enter the post (an example).
Can someone please review this code:
   <!-- start portfolio -->
    <section class="page-section portfolio-wrap">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div {block:SearchPage}style="display: none;"{/block:SearchPage}{block:TagPage}style="display: none;"{/block:TagPage}>{block:IfPostAreaTitle}<h3>{text:Post Area Title}</h3>{/block:IfPostAreaTitle}</div>

          {block:TagPage}<h3>{lang:Posts tagged Tag}</h3>{/block:TagPage}
          {block:SearchPage}<h3>{lang:Search results for SearchQuery}</h3><p>{lang:SearchResultCount results}</p>{block:NoSearchResults}<h3>{lang:No results found}</h3>{/block:NoSearchResults}{/block:SearchPage}
          <div class="divider"></div>
        </div>

          <div class="large-12 columns portfolio">

            {block:Posts}
            <article class="large-3 medium-6 columns">
              
               {block:Photo}
               <div id="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url('{PhotoURL-500}');">
            
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <a href="{Permalink}" title="{lang:Permalink for this post}"></a>
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}<br>{/block:Caption}
                        {block:IfShowPostDate}{block:Date}<small>{lang:Posted on DayOfMonth Month Year}</small>{/block:Date}{/block:IfShowPostDate}
                    </div>
                </div>
               {/block:Photo}

               {block:Photoset}
                <div id="portfolio-item" {block:Photos}style="background-image: url('{PhotoURL-500}');"{/block:Photos}> 

                    <div class="post-info">
                        <a href="{Permalink}" class="post-info" title="{lang:Permalink for this post}"></a>
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}<br>{/block:Caption}
                        {block:IfShowPostDate}{block:Date}<small>{lang:Posted on DayOfMonth Month Year}</small>{/block:Date}{/block:IfShowPostDate}<br>
                        <small>{PhotoCount} {lang:Photos}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
               {/block:Photoset}



.........................................................


Can you post a link to the actual blog? I suspect it relates to the css (although it might be part of the theme)

There's also id attributes in the template which could appear multiple times on the page.  Id's should be unique.

OK I am not 100% sure as yet, but I think the issue lies with this line (although there could be more issues of course) <div id="portfolio-item" style="background-image: url('{PhotoURL-500}');"> the PhotoURL-500 is not being parsed correctly as far as I can tell. Do you mind copying and pasting the entire tumblr html into something like JSBin? I might be able to replicate the issue then. https://jsbin.com/
Here is an example where I hard coded the background image. https://i.imgur.com/axORd4J.png

Here's the link where you can download the html code - https://mega.nz/file/EIpFDaab#XFdVO-ivGHCQ7bvcIg_CqxjaFYqC5VcKUhTnkFGCi1Q

OK, I know the problem I think and I don't think there is much you can do about it unfortunately. The theme is relatively old and would work when using the old style Tumblr posts system when each post had a specified type. But Tumblr now uses something called NPF (Neue Posts Format) it doesn't really care about the post type, because any post can contain any type of content (or a mixture). See this comment: https://themeforest.net/item/vincere-business-tumblr-theme/reviews/7414016

In order to test this I have made this: https://madox-test.tumblr.com/ if you scroll down you will some older posts loading with the correct content. And you can also check the archive: https://madox-test.tumblr.com/archive the 3 I just made today use the NPF format older ones don't and work in the theme. There might be a way to code this up to get it to do what you want to do, but I think you would have to pay a developer, it would be expensive, a new modern theme should circumvent these issues, plus it seems there are other problems with the old theme (http vs https)

Oh hang on it looks like you submitted that review, right?

I have already contacted the developer, no response from him. I guess I'll just buy a new theme. That seems to be the only solution, thank you so much for explaining and trying to help.

There are plenty of free themes, also maybe look out for something that is modern. Good luck.
